# Running .Net Software with a SQL database on other systems?

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I've created a software that is used a SQL database. (With VS2008 SP1 & C#)
What do I need to run this software on the other system without installing Visual Studio ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mostly two things:

- the correct version (.NET 3.5 Service Pack 1 - [download link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=AB99342F-5D1A-413D-8319-81DA479AB0D7&displaylang=en)) of the .NET framework for your application
- a suitable SQL Server (Express edition, or a access to a full-fledged SQL Server in the network)

You can download the free SQL Server 2008 R2 Express from this link here:

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/R2Downloads.aspx

Comment: Th correct version of .NET framework in this case will be .NET framework 3.5 SP1 which you can download from: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=ab99342f-5d1a-413d-8319-81da479ab0d7&displaylang=en

Comment: I've used SQLExpress 2008 for creating the software, Could you please post the link of the installing file that I have to install it on the destination system?